# Android ListView: Change from Scrolling Header to Sticky

Tags: android, listview, scroll, sticky

How can I make a header inside a listview that scrolls normally but when you scroll down too much so that it would vanish at the top it becomes fixed/sticky at the top.

I have added the header with addHeaderView but I suppose this isn't possible if you want to implement what I described.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a 3rd party library that can do exactly what you want right here

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

the ability to do this is not in the SDK

Comment: It uses a FrameLayout to build the ListView. So when you are using ListActivity this lib is not for you.