# How to freeze header and footer in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have added header and footer in a ListView, I just don't know how to freeze them when the list is being scrolled. Please kindly help me. (The code below just for header only)

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Relativelayout01"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:paddingLeft="12dip">

<TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:text="Age"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/name">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

listview_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Relativelayout01"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:paddingLeft="12dip">

<TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nameheader"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:text="Age"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ageheader"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameheader"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameheader"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/nameheader">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

DbHelper.java

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="bebook_db";

    public DbHelper(Context context){
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT,Age INTEGER); ");

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put("Name", "Anna");
            cv.put("Age", 19);
            db.insert("mytable", "Name", cv);

            cv.put("Name", "Jane");
            cv.put("Age", 21);
            db.insert("mytable", "Name", cv);

            cv.put("Name", "Mary");
            cv.put("Age", 17);
            db.insert("mytable", "Name", cv);

            //We can add more data here to test the scrolling effect.
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable");
            onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase  db = null;
    private Cursor cursor = null;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header, null); 
       ListView listView = getListView();  
       listView.addHeaderView(header); 

       db= (new DbHelper (getApplicationContext())).getWritableDatabase();        
       cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,Name, Age from mytable ORDER BY Age", null);

       adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                       R.layout.listview, 
                       cursor, 
                       new String[]{"Name","Age"},
                       new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.age},1);
       setListAdapter(adapter);

   }

    protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       cursor.close();
       db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ListView: Change from Scrolling Header to Sticky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902898/android-listview-change-from-scrolling-header-to-sticky)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to investigate [sticky list headers](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders).
As a note, this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902898/android-listview-change-from-scrolling-header-to-sticky).

Comment: It seems to0 complicated for a begginner, is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach without using any third-party library. You don't need to use a `ListActivity`. You can retrieve a listview widget from `xml` and in that layout where your `ListView` lives, you can create header and footer there. But remember to add margins in the top and bottom of the `ListView`. Otherwise, your header and footer will not be visible. Here  is a sample `xml` I used in my project -

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView  //header 
        android:id="@+id/sTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/iDlockedAppListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sTextView1"           
        android:layout_below="@+id/sTextView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" //remember to add margin top
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" // and bottom
         >

    </ListView>




    <Button  // footer 
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to add a viewgroup, you can replace header and footer elements with nested layouts. Hope that helps